# Check if VC++ Redistributable 10 is installed through perl script

Tags: perl, winapi, visual-c++, registry, redistributable

I am writing a perl script to check if the Visual C++ Redistributable 2010 x64 is installed in the system already.

I came across two ways according to https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2010/05/05/mailbag-how-to-detect-the-presence-of-the-visual-c-2010-redistributable-package/

To read the registry for the corresponding entry.
or to use `MsiQueryProductStateA`

Using `Win32::TieRegistry` is not a possible option with out per setup.

but using `use Win32::API` is an option

Trying to use `MsiQueryProductStateA` with `Win32::API`

```
use Win32::API;
$function = Win32::API::More->Import(
    'msi', 'INSTALLSTATE  MsiQueryProductStateA(LPCSTR szProduct)'
);
```

Supposed to get some valid return value but getting error

```
Win32::API::parse_prototype: WARNING unknown output parameter type 'INSTALLSTATE' at C:\Program Files\HP\HP BTO Software\nonOV\Perl\a\lib/5.26.2/MSWin32-x64-multi-thread/Win32/API.pm line 600. 4294967294
```

Could someone please shed some light on how to use/ import the return type as well and how to use this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can try to use `int` instead of `INSTALLSTATE`.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT it returns -2 for all the product ids whether it is installed or not.

Comment: `INSTALLSTATE_INVALIDARG   = -2,  // invalid function argument` So make sure you include brace enclose the product code like this `"{196BB40D-1578-3D01-B289-BEFC77A11A1E}"`

Answer (score 0):

Show how to implement in C++ (not in perl) you can refer to.

I installed [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads).

[image]

[image]

Return value 5 indicate "[The product is installed for the current user.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/msi/nf-msi-msiqueryproductstatea#return-value)"

Find the product code in registry like this:

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Dependencies\Microsoft.VS.VC_RuntimeAdditionalVSU_x86,v14

Comment: Thanks Rita Han, this should anyway work in C++. My original issue was solved with the comment mentioned above.

Comment: @DeepakSelvakumar Glad to help. You can accept my answer or write one for perl in order to help others are searching on this topic. Thanks.